# Why a matrix has to be invertible for $\operatorname{adj} A^T=(\operatorname{adj}A)^T$ to be true?

Tags: matrices, adjoint-operators, transpose

I read a theorem

> If $A$ is an invertible square matrix, then $\operatorname{adj} A^T= (\operatorname{adj} A)^T$.

But after attempting to prove it myself and also reading the proof I am unable to tell why the function needs to be invertible for above to be true.
As in the proof we no where use this condition.

**Proof:**

> $$\begin{align} A \operatorname{adj}A & =|A|I_n \\
> \implies (A \operatorname{adj} A)^T & = \{|A|I_n\}^T\\
> \implies (\operatorname{adj} A)^T(A^T) & =|A|I_n  \tag{1}\\
> \text{Also,}\\
> (\operatorname{adj} A^T)(A^T) & = |A^T|I_n \\
> (\operatorname{adj} A^T)(A^T) & = |A|I_n \tag{2}\\
> \text{from (1) and (2), we get} \\
> (\operatorname{adj}A^T)(A^T)& =(\operatorname{adj} A)^T(A^T)\\
> \implies \operatorname{adj} A^T&=(\operatorname{adj} A)^T
> \end{align}$$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144589/discussion-on-question-by-garuda-supermemo-why-a-matrix-has-to-be-invertible-for); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already used $A$ invertible in the last step, where you removed $A^T$ on the right on both sides.

But you are right that this theorem does not need A to be invertible. By definition
$$(\mathbb{adj}A)^T = \begin{bmatrix}A_{11} & A_{21} & \cdots & A_{n1}\\A_{12}&A_{22}&\cdots&A_{n2}\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\A_{1n}&A_{2n}&\cdots&A_{nn}\end{bmatrix}^T=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11} & A_{12} & \cdots & A_{1n}\\A_{21}&A_{22}&\cdots&A_{2n}\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\A_{n1}&A_{n2}&\cdots&A_{nn}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}{A^T}_{11} & {A^T}_{21} & \cdots & {A^T}_{n1}\\{A^T}_{12}&{A^T}_{22}&\cdots&{A^T}_{n2}\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\{A^T}_{1n}&{A^T}_{2n}&\cdots&{A^T}_{nn}\end{bmatrix}=\mathbb{adj}(A^T)$$

Here $A_{ij} = (-1)^{i+j}\mathbb{det}B_{ij},$ where $B_{ij}$ is the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix you get when you remove the i-th row and the j-th column of $A$. And ${A^T}_{ji} = (-1)^{i+j}\mathbb{det}C_{ji},$ where $C_{ji}$ is what you get when you remove the j-th row and the i-th column of $A^T$. You could directly check that $B_{ij}=(C_{ji})^T$, which implies thay have the same determinant, and hence $A_{ij}={A^T}_{ji}$.

Comment: how $A_{11}$ is equal to $A_{11}^T$

Comment: @garudasupermemo Eliminating the first row and the first column of $A$ and $A^T$ will get matrices transposing to each other, and they have the same determinant.

Comment: @lxklp I am unable to understand your last part of the solution can you elaborate further, or if you are willing to we can discuss on apps like discord.

Comment: Vseh and Garuda, the entries of the adjugate matrix are defined e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix), and lxklp's explanation for $(A^T)_{ij}= A_{ji}$ in the case $i=j=1$ naturally adapts to the general case. Garuda, beware the flip on the indices in this equality.

Comment: @garudasupermemo: Note that $A_{12}$ equals $A_{21}^T$, not $A_{12}^T$.

Comment: can someone give me algebraic proof for this theorem if it is true even if A is invertible

Comment: ? This proof *is* algebraic, and is the simplest one (+1). I wonder why it first got a downvote.

Comment: @AnneBauval is there a proof like mine. and also if this is true(which now I think it is) then why does the theorem starts like that and can it be used even A is non-invertible.

Comment: @garudasupermemo You can use your proof as so: approximate a singular $A$ by a sequence of nonsingular $A_k$ and then use the continuity of $\operatorname{adj}$ w.r.t. the entries of $A_k$, and your proof to arrive at the same conclusion for singular matrices.

Comment: @AnneBauval The definitions should be contained in the answer; one need not go search for them in external sources.

Comment: Garuda, there is no proof "like" "yours" for the singular case, but the singular case can be deduced from the regular one in $M_n(K)$ by density of $GL_n(K)$ when e.g. $K=\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C.$ For general (commutative) fields or even rings, the singular case can also be deduced from the regular one by sophisticated arguments of genericity. But all this is really not worthwile when you have got such an elementary direct proof. Note that "your" proof is less elementary: it relies on more knowledge.

Comment: (follow up) Since this proof holds for all cases (invertible or not), of course the theorem "can be used even A is non-invertible". As for "why does the theorem starts like that": may be (?) the author did not need the general case, or was not aware of it.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. I gave this link only to help you, but these definitions are common knowledge in this context. so honestly, they did not need to be included. Anyway, now they are.

Comment: P.S. for Garuda. I just saw Hans Lundmark's comments above. These are exactly the "sophisticated arguments of genericity" I alluded to here above, 14 min ago.

Comment: @AnneBauval I appreciate the help (even though I didn't really need it :) ) These definitions are not "common" knowledge for beginners in linear algebra, which the OP clearly is, hence the argument "here's the link, go do your own research" is, while encouraging, not necessarily helpful. Even then, said link, or similar, should've been included in the answer, if not a complete definition. But I rest my case.

Comment: Imo, someone (even a beginner) asking on this site for explanation about a theorem should be aware of the definition it involves.